# set length for Edittext

Tags: java, android

I need to set length for edittext.I cant set the length for edittext because I am using the equals method in that.

Below I am posted the relevant code.I need to perform validation for edittext.If the edittext length less than 0.then it wouldn't move to new activity.

```
 if (!editText.getText().toString().equals("c") && !editText.getText().toString().equals("c1"))
 {

 Intent i2 = new Intent(First.this, Second.class);
 startActivity(i2);

 }
.....
.....

String strUserName = editText.getText().toString();

   if(TextUtils.isEmpty(strUserName)) {
       //  editText.setError("Your message");
       Toast.makeText(First.this,"Please enter number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return;
```

My only issue is,Edittext move to another activity if the value is null.I have to restrict it by setting a length to stay in this activity.

Anyone can help me with this.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Edittext move to another activity if the value is null.

Because :

```
 if (!editText.getText().toString().equals("c") && 
                           !editText.getText().toString().equals("c1"))
```

condition is `true` when Editext `getText()` method return `null` or any other value excluding `c` and `c1`.

Add `null` and empty check before check value for `c` and `c1` String.like:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(strUserName)) {
  // show Toast message when value is empty
}else if (!editText.getText().toString().equals("c") && 
                               !editText.getText().toString().equals("c1")){
    // start next Activity if text is equals to `c` and `c1`
}
```

Comment: is it possible to set length to editttext to stay in this activity,if the value is null.I am sure,I am checking with null value.

Comment: @user10: what do you mean by set length to EditText?

Comment: sorry now only checking your answer.you were right.wait I will tick this answer.working good.thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if the your EditText doesn't return null.
2. If you would enter anything beside c or c 1 it would take you to the next activity, why? because your condition checks if  the String inside your EditText is either c or c1, if it's not C or C1 open Second activity.